# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value setting a label's text

Tags: ios, swift

Здравствуйте, я учу swift для школьного проекта и у меня возникла проблема с опциональными значениями.

Я получаю ошибку, когда должен измениться текст в resultlab, которая прикреплена к label. Все значения высчитываются правильно, что я вижу в системе, но попытка изменить текст label или выдаёт ошибку или с label ничего не происходит .

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Здесь Мой Код

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var sextype: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var traning: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var resultlab: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

@IBAction func result(_ sender: Any) {
    var bmr: Double = 0
    var bmi: Double = 0

    if let age = Int(text1.text!) {
        if let height = Int(text3.text!) {
            if let weight = Int(text2.text!) {

                switch sextype.selectedSegmentIndex {
                case 0:
                    bmr = 88.362 + 13.397 * Double(weight) + 4.799 * Double(height) - 5.677 * Double(age)
                case 1:bmr = 447.593 + 9.247 * Double(weight) + 3.098 * Double(height) - 4.330 * Double(age)
                default:
                    bmr = 0
                }
                bmi = Double(weight) / pow(Double(height) / 100, 2)
            }
        }
    }
    let factor = [1.375, 1.55, 1.725, 1.9, 2.7, 2.8, 3.6]
    let selectedFactor = factor[traning.selectedSegmentIndex]
    bmr *= selectedFactor
    //Ошибка на следующей строке
        resultlab.text="Вы должны потреблять \(bmr) килокалорий для поддержания веса.\nИндекс массы тела \(bmi)."

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.endEditing(true)

}
```

Я пробовал делать unwrap/convert этой строки, но всё бестолку. Помогите пожалуйста, на английском стаке меня отправляют по различным темам из которых я толком ничего не могу вынести.

Comment: значит resultlab не соединена с UILabel в Storyboard.

Comment: @VAndrJ соединена, проверял много раз

Comment: попробуй ввести условие if let resultlab = self.resultlab { изменяешь код } else { print("label = nil!") } и по результатам уже смотреть, в чём косяк

Comment: очень странно, в процессе попыток перенести весь код в другой кастомный класс и последующего возврата его в ViewController проблема решилась сама. Я не знаю как это произошло, если учесть что я ничего не поменял. Вопрос решён, спасибо всем.